# Swagger 3.0.0: Can't disable in production without SwaggerConfig and @Profile

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox-boot-starter

I'm upgrading to SpringFox Swagger 3.0.0 from 2.x, which introduces the Spring Boot starter `springfox-boot-starter` dependency that obviates the need for the 2.x-based `SwaggerConfig`:

```
/**
 * NO LONGER NEEDED
 */
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@Profile({"local", "dev", "beta"}) // <- HOW TO DISABLE IN PROD INSTEAD OF THIS
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Now that I no longer need this `@Configuration`, which allows me to specify my environment profiles in `@Profile` and therefore disable Swagger in production, how do I disable Swagger in production in SpringFox Swagger-UI 3.x?

NOTE: There is Spring Security-based approached discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61337019/spring-disable-swagger-ui-for-production) that could be an option for some, but is not an option for this scenario for two reasons:

- My application does not use Spring Security and it is not possible to include the `spring-boot-security-starter` dependency
- It requires whitelisting all other endpoints in order to get them working again, which is not acceptable

Comment: You may try the @Profile({"!prod"}) and in your application property, add spring.profiles=prod springfox.documentation.enabled=false

Comment: Thanks just saw this after posting reference to answer below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer was not easy to find and was NOT in SpringFox's migration guide or documentation [here](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/) (where it should be).

The CORRECT and by far best answer for Swagger UI 3.0.0 is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66265231/2735802).

Just add `springfox.documentation.enabled=[true|false]` to the target environment's application.properties or application.yml.

As an aside, it would be nice to see a section with the list of all available Spring Boot properties listed in the SpringFox doc.